# When does Scandinavian Mountains Airport open?

Tags: airports, sweden, event-based-effects, norway, scr

I remember drawing Sälen Trysil Airport on Google Maps back when it was called that, but since then the airport (then an airstrip) has been converted into an international airport. When does it open for commercial flights?

Comment: Right at the start of the Vasaloppet, interesting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The airport is set to open 22 December 2019.

The new or radically rebuilt airport is called Scandinavian Mountains Airport, which is rather unspecific as it will not be the only airport in the Scandinavian Mountains and the mountain range stretches 1700 km.